# How do I perform concurrent save/update in MongoDB/Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, concurrency

While trying to perform two simultaneous updates (at the same time) to the same document MongoDB/Mongoose is dropping the first request and writing the second one only. Is this because of MongoDB failing to serve concurrent requests?

```
Storage.findOneAndUpdate("charger", {
    chargeBoxIdentity: "209348",
},
{
    $set: { connectors: [3,65] },
}).then(()=>{ .... })
```

I can see in my logs that the update methods are getting called. If it's due to a race condition then how can I avoid the issue?

Comment: You'll need to call the .save() method after making your first request

Comment: @Vishwak I'm using `findOneAndUpdate` as it supports atomic update. What I'm not sure if the issue is because of a race condition and how can I avoid it? 
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html